# Delay not introduced in a query - Jscript

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 Paragraph tags inside a div with id=address

I want to append a character to this paragraph from a string array.

I want that each character should be added after a finite delay.

here is the code snippet:

```
  $("#address p").each(function(index)
  {
   var t_delay = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<arr[index].length; i++){
    t_delay += 1000;
    $(this).delay(t_delay).append(arr[index][i]);
   }
  });
```

I am not getting the delay, and the whole paragraph displays all together.

pls help me

Comment: I think your code snippet is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

use `stop()`in this case......

```
$("#address p").each(function(index) { 
  //use stop with id of paragraph
```

or you can also use `setTimeOut()..`
also you can use `delay()`......here it's reference [delay in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

Delay is only for adding a pause to the animation queue. 
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

For delaying code execution, you have to use setTimeout.

```
$("#address p").each(function(index)
{

    var t_delay = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<arr[index].length; i++){
        t_delay += 1000;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).append(arr[index][i]);
        }, t_delay);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $("#address p").each(function(index)
  {
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).append(arr[index][i]);
  });
```